# Add Default Thread to Gitlab Merge Requests

Tags: automation, gitlab, jira, cicd, merge-request

I'd like to add a default Thread to every merge request that gets created for my Gitlab project. This would be automatically added on MR creation, and used to display a checklist of administrative items that need to be completed before the issue is ready to be merged (things like logging time worked on the issue in JIRA, and filling out other fields of the issue).

I haven't been able to find such an option in digging through project settings, or looking online. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considered using a [webhook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html)?

Comment: I have not. Can you walk through what the workflow might look like here?

Comment: You can use a webhook to signal an application to respond to events in GitLab. One of the events you can subscribe to are merge request events, including when a merge request is created. When your application receives the webhook event, you can program it to use the GitLab API to create a thread on the MR.